# How to get values in a pandas dataframe column between 2 times?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where the date_time column was separated into date and time. This is so date could be used separately from time in different scenarios. But now I need to get the time values between 5:00 - 8:00. I only find functions in pandas for datetimes. Is there any way to ONLY get values from a time column?

I think part of the issue is the data type for the time column. I have tried to remove the colon in the time value, so that 5:00 becomes 500. But I still am unable to choose the values I need. I keep getting a Key error on 'time'.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
# Get bird sightings between 5-8am. Remove the colon in time first.
early_birds_df = france_df['time'].str.replace(':','')

# Convert time to a numeric data type, so we can treat it like a number
early_birds_df['time'] = pd.to_numeric(early_birds_df['time'], errors='coerce')
early_birds_df.head()
```

But this returns an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'time'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'time'
```

Here is a code snippet to use as an example. I want to use the `time' column and it has an index of sorts. Let's say I want to retrieve all rows that are between the times of 1:00 and 3:10. What code can I use to do that?

```
        date        time
1       8/15/2013   0:18
2       8/15/2013   0:48
3       8/15/2013   1:17
4       8/15/2013   1:47
5       8/15/2013   2:17
6       8/15/2013   2:47
7       8/15/2013   3:02
8       8/15/2013   3:17
9       8/15/2013   3:32
10      8/15/2013   3:47
```

Comment: have you tried `pd.to_timedelta` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html

Comment: @Riley, thanks, but I can't quite make sense of timedelta. I could convert my series of times to a TimeDelta type, but then those types come with a lot of "baggage" added to the time values (adding words like 'hours'). Also, not sure how to get the range of values, it seems TimeDelta is more about getting the difference between two values. I wonder if it's simpler just to have an additional date_time column (recombine my date and time), because there is a nice between_time() function that would work. It's not ideal to have a date_time and a time and date columns, but might be all I can find.

Comment: If you have a `pandas.Series` of timestamps (call it `s`) then `s.dt.time` will get you the time component, and `s.dt.date` will get you a date component.  These components both come from `datetime` module.

Comment: A timedelta is the difference between two values, but a "time with no date" is just the difference between the start of the date and the time, so they're essentially equivalent. The words things you mention are just how it displays on your console.  If you wanted to convert a `pandas.Series` of timedeltas to numbers you can use `mytimedeltas.dt.seconds` to get the number of seconds, or divide it by another timedelta eg `pd.Timedelta("1hr")`.

Comment: If you put some code for constructing a small example of your data in your question I'll show you how to use it.

Comment: @Riley thanks! My brain is so fried right now, I'm having a hard time to think. But I have added a code snippet with a goal needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the times are between hourly values, then you can use (for your example of 5:00 and 8:00)

```
df[df["date_time"].dt.hour.between(5,8)]
```

To be more general you can use `pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time` but this requires converting your timestamp series to a `DatetimeIndex` first, i.e.

```
df["date_time"].iloc[pd.DatetimeIndex(df["date_time"]).indexer_between_time("05:00", "08:00")]
```

or you can convert the times to their corresponding timedeltas since the start of the day, and then compare against timedelta values, eg

```
time = df["date_time"] - df["date_time"].dt.floor("D")
df[time.between(pd.Timedelta("05:00:00"), pd.Timedelta("08:00:00"))]
```

**edit**

Just saw the new data format with `time` column.  In that case you can append seconds to the strings so that we can work with `to_timedelta`, eg

```
pd.to_timedelta(df["time"] + ":00").between(pd.to_timedelta("05:00:00"), pd.to_timedelta("08:00:00"))
```

Comment: Thanks, trying the first one! I had my code: `early_birds_df = france_df[france_df['date_time'].dt.hour.between(5,8)]` but it gave an error: `Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

Comment: that'd be because they're either strings, or `datetime.datetime` , which can be fixed with `to_datetime`

Comment: I converted the `date_time` like this: `france_df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(france_df['date_time'])` and it totally worked! I can't thank you enough. Big presentation tomorrow, now I'm ready. :)